# What links should social share copy contain?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, social-media, sharing

When users share my content on public share platforms including Facebook, Twitter, Tumblr, etc., what is the best experience for users on mobile devices?

1. Click shared link --> mobile website that contains a 'get the app' prompt
2. Click shared link --> check if user has the app --> if yes: open app; if no: app store;

I should mention that my app is very much mobile first. Users can only contribute by using the app while the website is read-only. Thus, it's a much less complete experience on web, but it may be useful to users to see the content that was shared before being prompted to download the app.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, include some imagery for visual learners, etc.?  I am a little uncertain as to what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: So you're asking which pathway experience to offer to the visiting user?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to share via apps only. Mentioned social networks above all have APIs for mobile web as well. If you implement it correct, this is the flow:

1. User click *Share* and selects social network
2. If social network app is available - open new post page
3. Else open new post page on mobile website of social network

To be prompted on downloading from App Store every time a user shares something breaks the users intended workflow. There may be a number of reasons why the App isn't available on this device, such as storage limitations, performance issues, borrowed device and more. Most important, we don't know why it's not there, and shouldn't prompt the user before sharing. When the post have been made, we can always add the familiar 'view in App Store' banner at the top, to remind the user in a friendly way. But always after the intended action.